# iPhone shows 1.3GB of photos but I don't have any

Tags: iphone, photos, storage

Edited:

Orginal question: 
My iPhone 4S shows that I have 1.3GB of photos but I don't have any. 
How to empty this amount of space and make it available?

I go to "settings" -> "general" -> "usage" -> "manage storage" and then "Photos & Camera" shows that there is 1.3GB of using space but I have no photos at all. So I go to that "Photos & Camera" and I see that "Shared Photo Stream" takes most of it, so about 1.3GB but I don't share any photos. 
But! If I take one photo using camera and then it appears in "Photos" -> "Camera Roll" then I go to "settings" -> "general" -> "usage" -> "manage storage" -> "Photos & Camera" then it shows that "Photo Library" uses almost 1.3GB of storage space in my iPhone and "Shared Photo Stream" almost none. And if I delete this one photo then "Shared Photo Stream" shows that there is almost 1.3GB using space and "Photo Library" uses almost none.

I use iOS 8 but before when there was iOS7 the problem was the same and it was the main reason why I updated to iOS8 because I was hopping it resolves this problem but the problem is still there.

Help please
End of original question.

Added latter:
No matter which iOS and build is installed same problem was even if the newest iOS is installed. I said was coz
only solution is to instal for example iExplorer on PC then plug in iPhone to PC and using iExplorer delete all picture cache data on iPhone. It seams picture cache on iPhone is kept even if iPhone was restored to complete factory setting and set as new. As I said problem solved by third party software. Apple has had no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Turn off the shared photo stream.

Comment: Emil - please edit this to include - what version of iOS is installed (settings -> general -> about) and give the full string as well as the build. e.g. 8.1.3 (12B466)

Comment: Here i found the solution .... on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WT3Z0Hals4 ... Actually its problem comes on iOS 8, when iPhone introduced Recently Deleted Photos option there is a bug in this it actually do not delete photos by it self ... you have to delete them manually.

Comment: This is solved here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179746/153510

Comment: I have 8.5 GB used up by photos right now, but I have zero photos. Already deleted all from "recently deleted photos".

Comment: Jonny if you have the same problem as mine then you have to use iExplorer. It's a software that shows all data on your iPhone. You have to delete all picture cache data then problem will be solved.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure I have your answer!  I just had the same problem myself.

It seems that the Photos app has a "nice feature" called "Recently Deleted" that CONTINUES TO KEEP deleted photos on your device for a certain period of time.  SO ... Just click on your photos app, then click on its RECENTLY DELETED folder, then empty its contents.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried syncing your iPhone with iTunes? If that doesn't work I typically go into

settings->general->reset->erase all content and settings and erase all content.

Make sure that you turn off iCloud photos to eliminate this from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy the additional iCloud storage.  I couldn't figure it out, then bought the 20gb for $.99 a month and it immediately cleared all the phantom pictures out.  I now have plenty of space on my phone.