# Why does my iPhone still think I have 7gb of pictures on it even after I deleted all of them?

Tags: iphone, storage

I didn't have any space left on iCloud so I went to check what's going on there. I saw that my iPhone was taking up a lot of storage. My storage for pictures was still 7gb even after I deleted all of my pictures. I'm not even sharing any pictures and I also deleted all of my recently deleted pictures. All of them. Why is it still showing me under "usage" that I have 7gbs? I'm not able to backup my phone because I apparently I don't have any space when really I don't have 7gbs of pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Pictures can be stored in many application bundles. Could you upload a screen shot of what specifically you are looking at to measure the 7 GB? Also, are you just looking to do a backup or are you looking to prune the storage itself. We like to have one question per question so that a good answer to each can be identified with the check mark. If you need both, edit this to clearly ask one question and go ahead and [ask] the second question on the site.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it for me: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179746/153510

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to look in the recently deleted album. They stay there for 30 days unless you go in there and delete them permanently.

Comment: I did I did. I deleted everything that has to do with my pictures. Also there is no sharing and nothing is being shared. Thanks though