# Where are the phantom/ghost files in iOS Photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, storage

I'm experiencing the infamous ["phantom/ghost" photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159311/iphone-shows-1-3gb-of-photos-but-i-dont-have-any) issue on my iPhone (XS Max; iOS 16). In short, I have deleted *all* photos on my phone, including from the `Recently Deleted` album, but my iPhone is still reporting that the `Photos` app is using 1.1G.

**Ultimate questions**:

1. Where are the phantom photos/files if they're not in `Media`?
2. If the phantom photos/files are not actually there, does anyone know how `iPhone Storage` calculates usage for the `Photos` app?

**What I've done**:

I've tried the normal tricks of setting the date back, restarting phone, etc. Most recently, I used [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to browse through the `Media` folder on my iPhone looking for phantom/ghost photos lingering around. I wasn't able to find anything in the normal spots, so I mounted the `Media` directory on my Mac and measured the size of all files/folders under `Media` to see where the phantom data are hiding (`du -sch *`), but I don't see anything that explains the 1.1G of data iOS is reporting in `Photos` (see image). The largest folder is `iTunes_Control` at 6.4G. Of course, my understanding is that `iTunes_Control` is purely limited to the `Music` app, and it matches what `iPhone Storage` reports for the `Music` app. Everything else is only 0.3G.

Really appreciate your help.

[image: Folder sizes under Media]

Comment: Could I get some feedback on this question? i.e., do I have no responses because it's off-topic, unclear, no one knows? The general issue of phantom photos is very well documented out on the "interwebs", as it were, but I don't see posts out there describing what I'm seeing (or not seeing) here.

Answer (score 1):

So I risked it and tried messing with some files with iExplorer. It seems the `Photos` app storage counts both the media files by themselves and its database file `Photos.sqlite` (and `Photos.sqlite-shm` and `Photos.sqlite-wal`, I guess), stored on the `PhotoData` folder. It seems this file must have become corrupted, because the entries on `PhotoData/BackupDatabase` went at one point from ~10-20 MB to multiple 1 GB copies.

I deleted the bigger entries in that subfolder (in my case, `20230326`, containing numbered folders "0+" with the backups), replaced the one directly on `PhotoData` with a previous entry, and restarted my phone. Upon reopening the `Photos` app, it starts out as having no photos, and then they start to appear again (I suppose it was the database file regenerating), then checking `iPhone Storage` it seems the app went back to an appropiate size. Checking the `PhotoData` folder again, there's a new, leaner `Photos.sqlite`, and it seems the one I replaced was renamed to `Photos.sqlite.aside` (so I'm not sure if a replacement file is needed when deleting the bloated one).

Apologies if there's some parts that aren't clear, I'm not really a programmer.

Comment: Hello, @José. Thanks so much for the response! The rub for me is that I don't have the same issue. As shown in my screenshot in the original post, the *total* size of the entire `PhotoData` folder (including hidden files) on my iPhone is only `181M`. I just checked again (both on the command line and in iExplorer) to be certain. All of the database files you mention are `<20M` (each). Yet, the `Photos` app under `iPhone Storage` still reports `>1G`. I just can't see how iOS is reporting such high usage.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `DCIM` folder is basically empty, too (`1.8M`), as shown above.